# Изменить вид клавиатуры в альбомной ориентации

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-search-view

При использовании стандартного EditText, в альбомной ориентации всплывающая клавиатура имеет собственное поле ввода.[image: Поле ввода в альбомной ориентации]

Мне нужно, чтобы всплывала только клавиатура, так как я использую поле ввода для поиска элементов и они должны динамически во время ввода показываться в списке результатов под полем, а такая клавиатура перекрывает весь экран. 
При использовании встроенного SearchView проблема решается, но его слишком сложно кастомизировать, поэтому для поиска использую EditText. 
Возможно ли решить эту проблему? Или обычный EditText не имеет такой возможности?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Решил проблему. Для того чтобы отключить стандартное поле ввода для альбомной ориентации, необходимо установить для EditText такое свойство:

```
android:imeOptions="flagNoExtractUi"
```